# Not loading library : rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Searched before posting, I could not able to fix the issue and I'm getting the following library errors and I'm not sure how to fix this and I don't have Ruby background so be gentle with me.

on my machine I have openssl version is : LibreSSL 2.8.3

Any help please?

```
/Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
    
      Refere

nced from: /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha1.bundle

  Reason: image not found - /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha1.bundle

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:122:in `<class:LockfileParser>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:14:in `<module:Bundler>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:129:in `definition'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:95:in `setup'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'

from /Users/john.doe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
```

Comment: Reinstall OpenSSL, reinstall Ruby. (`rvm uninstall 2.3.1; rvm install 2.3.1`)

Comment: after uninstall and install now i'm getting this error `could not find multipart-post2.0.0 in any of the source`

Comment: Change into your app directory and run `bundle install`, then retry.

Comment: can you post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Ruby can't find the version of OpenSSL that it was compiled with. Reinstall OpenSSL (through whatever means you care to, e.g., `brew install openssl`), then reinstall Ruby:

```sh
rvm uninstall 2.3.1
rvm install 2.3.1
```

Once Ruby has been reinstalled, install your gems:

```sh
bundle install
```

Then retry your operation.

Comment: important note: it only works for me when `Change into app directory and run bundle install`